# Google Sheet array range

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, range

I am trying to create categories of scores using the array formula in Google Sheets where 0-17 = low, 18-23 = moderate, and 24+ = high. My current formula works for low and high but I am getting "FALSE" for the moderate column.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(T2<18,"Low",if(17<T2<24,"Moderate",if(T2>23,"High"))))
```

Suggestions for how to code the moderate range within the array formula or is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Doesnt Google Sheets have an AND operator? Can you do something like (t2>17 AND t2 <24) ?

Comment: I thought that would work as well but when I tried previously it gave me #ERROR!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=if(T2<18,"Low",if(T2<24,"Moderate","High"))
```

Comment: it is perfectly fine formula, but if you get error try replacing comma with semicolon (this is Google Sheets settings for some countries): '=if(T2<18,"Low",IF(T2<24,"Moderate","High"))'

Comment: Thanks! Adding the semicolon worked. Appreciate the help.